# ActionBar drawable background inconsistency

Tags: android, styles, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I have successfully set a background image on an Action Bar. I use ActionBarSherlock and in Android 2.x everything is ok. 
The problem is with Android 4.x. The background image change across activities. If I set the background to a solid colour, the looks is the same for all activities. If a set a drawable, sometimes it is lighter others darker.

My style file in values-14

```
 <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarBG</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarBG" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/top_bar_bg</item>
    </style>
```

Oddly when I took some screenshots to include in this question, all the images appear correctly. So I must assume this is a problem of the device (Samsung Galaxy SII). Anyone ever found a problem like this?

Comment: Why are you setting the android:background property twice at ActionBarBG? It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: You are right. I just edit the question. There was a line that supposed to be commented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested with other devices and I found out that it only happen with Samsung Galaxy SII. I am forced to conclude that it is a device problem.

Comment: It might be related to Samsung's TouchWiz interface which is added on top of the default android UI. If possible, try your app on an HTC device, which also has a custom UI to see if action from your side is required to stop this behaviour.